# Precaching HTML image resources

Tags: javascript

I wrote a [web cam viewer](http://cam.dabase.com/) where the [javascript source](http://cam.dabase.com/hgweb.cgi/file/tip/main.js) basically sources the image according to an "active" class in a list.

I was wondering what are good modern techniques to make images load faster in the background, so a user can get a better experience flicking through images.

Obviously it doesn't make sense to download all images, I imagine it needs to be like when one scrolls through a Google map in principle, images are loaded on demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't really looked into this specific technique before, but this is how I'd approach it:

```
$(function() {
    var src = [
        "https://developer.mozilla.org/skins/mdn/Transitional/img/mdn-logo-sm.png",
        "http://cdn.sstatic.net/programmers/img/logo.png?v=123",
        "http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/images/adobe.png"
    ];
    var loaded = [];
    var idx = 0;

    var sz = src.length;
    for(var n = 0; n < sz; ++n) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            loaded.push(this);
            if(sz === loaded.length) onLoaded();
        };
        img.src = src[n];
    }

    function onLoaded() {
        $("#next").removeClass("disabled").addClass("enabled");
    }

    $("#next").click(function(e) {
        if(!$(this).hasClass("disabled")) {
            e.preventDefault();
            idx = (idx + 1) % sz;

            $($("img")[0]).remove();
            $("#container").append(loaded[idx]);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbrecht/6MLHR/

In my fiddle sample, I only force the client to load the first image with the rest of the page. Then, on jQuery load (`$(function() {})`), I cache all other images I want to display with the script (3 images in this case).

Once each image has loaded, I push it into a cached array and check if the cached size equals the source size. If it does, then I call `onLoaded`.

One optimization to this might be to simply use the cache the image on the page rather than load another one (0th element in `src`).

Of course, this can easily be done with native Javascript as well, I chose to use jQuery for this example for no *real* good reason ;).

Comment: Thanks for your input. Since rewritten the code like so: https://github.com/kaihendry/Praze/blob/master/main.js where I just load the next next image. Performance is good enough for me!